# Play Live streaming video with 10 seconds prebuffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am working with an iOS application, in which I have to play the HTTP Live streaming video of file type **'.m3u8'**. So, I went through some tutorials and some how I've played HTTP live streaming videos in MPMoviePlayerController in iOS.

Now I want to prebuffer the video for 10 seconds in the background to play continue.Please help me with this. I'll be really very grateful to you.

Thanks in Advance.

Here's my code

```
  var moviestreamPlayer : MPMoviePlayerController =    MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: NSURL(string:"http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8"))

    movieStreamPlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(movieStreamPlayer.view)

    movieStreamPlayer.fullscreen = true
    movieStreamPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming
    // Play the movie!
    movieStreamPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    movieStreamPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
    if(movieStreamPlayer.isPreparedToPlay)
    {
        movieStreamPlayer.play()
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Nehal, Thanks for your comment. Now, can you please check that.